# html agility Returns incomprehensible text

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, html-agility-pack

When I am using html agility, I set the encoding to UTF-8. It works well when reading some texts, but in some cases it returns texts similar to the following text.

`&#x6F1;&#x6F3;&#x6F9;&#x6F9;-&#x6F1;&#x6F1;-&#x6F2;&#x6F0; &#x6F2;&#x6F3;:&#x6F2;&#x6F7;`

My code is almost as follows:

```
 HtmlWeb web2 = new HtmlWeb();
 web2.AutoDetectEncoding = false;
 web2.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF-8;
 var doc = await this.web2.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
  date = doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectNodes("/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]")
                    .First().InnerText;
```

I should add that it had the same problem without encoding.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-5.0)

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission
> into a decoded string.
>
> To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the
> [`WebUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility?view=net-5.0) class.

**Example**

```
var asd = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#x6F1;&#x6F3;&#x6F9;&#x6F9;-&#x6F1;&#x6F1;-&#x6F2;&#x6F0; &#x6F2;&#x6F3;:&#x6F2;&#x6F7;");
Console.WriteLine(asd);
```

**Output**

```
۱۳۹۹-۱۱-۲۰ ۲۳:۲۷
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0G7QpD)

Answer (score 1):

These are HTML entities representing the original text. If this is inside a web application you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` from the `System.Net` namespace. If this is outside of a webapplication you can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`, also from the `System.Net` namespace. This will change the HTML entities back into the corresponding text.

Running it through a fiddle resulted in

```
۱۳۹۹-۱۱-۲۰ ۲۳:۲۷
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/J7YXZM

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var encoded = "&#x6F1;&#x6F3;&#x6F9;&#x6F9;-&#x6F1;&#x6F1;-&#x6F2;&#x6F0; &#x6F2;&#x6F3;:&#x6F2;&#x6F7;";
        var decoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
        Console.WriteLine(decoded);
    }
}
```